# Alternatives for boost::multi_index

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, multi-index, boost-multi-index

I would like to use something which can create a dictionary like,

Multi-Keys

```
Key1                     which will map to              SomeObject
Key2
Key3
Key4
etc
```

I would like to look up based on any key. I have weird issues with boost::multi_index and am looking for alternatives.

My compiler is Visual Studio 2005 and I use boost and DONT USE C++11. Any boost(other than multi_index) stuff is most welcome.

Comment: Maybe if you could explain what "weird issues" you have with `boost::multi_index`  and we could help you solve them instead?

Comment: I'm with Joachim here.

Comment: Why would someone downvote my question?! I had a question and asked for an alternative! Why would I be downvoted?

Comment: I did not downvote. However you did not explain your weird issues. And it is offtopic to ask for a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you should get your weird issues fixed, but here's a technique that works nicely:

```
std::vector<X> v; // elements of X in some order
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<X const> > index1(v.begin(), v.end());
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<X const> > index2(v.begin(), v.end());

// sort the indexes
std::sort(index1.begin(), index1.end(), by_property1);
std::sort(index2.begin(), index2.end(), by_property2);
```

Of course, keeping things in synch under mutation and controlling the runtime cost of sorting the indexes becomes a slightly more tricky task, which is why - most of the time - you'd want `multi_index_container`

Also, note that to be more carefree, you'd need to replace `vector` with `list` there to enjoy iterator/reference stability.